# Recursive method c#

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

i made this recursive function, but after the "return" it jumps back to the line `GetProp(classes, obj);` and so it returns twice and I get a wrong value.

Thats how I call the method

```
foreach (string fieldKey in fieldKeys)
{
   Console.WriteLine(fieldKey);
   var props = fieldKey.Split('.');
   form.SetField(fieldKey, GetProp(props, inv));
}
```

Here is the method

```
public static string GetProp(string[] classes, object oldObj)
{
     var obj = oldObj.GetType().GetProperty(classes[0]).GetValue(oldObj, null);
     if(classes.Length>1)
     {
        classes = classes.Skip(1).ToArray();
        GetProp(classes, obj);
     }
        return obj.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I think you need to add a `return` keyword before `GetProp(classes, obj);` inside your `if` statement.

Comment: It does not return twice, it returns once on the `return` line, but you don't do anything with the result from the recursive call not sure what your business logic is, but inside the if shouldn't it be `return GetProp(classes, obj);` ? This would prevent the last return from executing

Comment: Thanks guys! How couldn't I see that.. Time for weekend

Answer (score 1):

You need the return at recursion i think.

```
 public static string GetProp(string[] classes, object oldObj)
 {
 var obj = oldObj.GetType().GetProperty(classes[0]).GetValue(oldObj, null);
 if(classes.Length>1)
   {
    classes = classes.Skip(1).ToArray();
    return GetProp(classes, obj);
   }
      return obj.ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need return the string when use recursive.

example:

```
public int recursive(int i){
    if(i == 1){
       i = i + 1;
       return recursive(i);
    }
    return i;
}
```

try with

```
return GetProp(classes, obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't jump this actually the most recent call returns to main call any way to fix this you need to return the most recent value just change `GetProp(classes,object);`
to `return GetProp(classes,object);`